# while loop still runs if 2 <= sqrt(2) is false?

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

If the user inputs 2, then the first run of the while loop says while `2 <= sqrt(2)`. Now, 2 is greater than the sqrt(2), so how does this program run? `2 <= sqrt(2)` would be false, so then what?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int  n;   // Number to test for prime-ness
    int  i;   // Loop counter
    int  is_prime = true;   // Boolean flag...
                            // Assume true for now.

    // Get a number from the keyboard.
    cout << "Enter a number and press ENTER: ";
    cin >> n;

    // Test for prime by checking for divisibility
    //  by all whole numbers from 2 to sqrt(n).
    i = 2;

    while (i <= sqrt(n)) {   // While i is <= sqrt(n),
        if (n % i == 0)        //  If i divides n,
            is_prime = false;  //    n is not prime.
        i++;                   //  Add 1 to i.
    }

    // Print results
    if (is_prime)
        cout << "Number is prime." << endl;
    else
        cout << "Number is not prime." << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: So the loop doesn't run.

Comment: What is your program's output? What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: By the way, if you're ever curious just what exactly it is that your program is doing, set a breakpoint to better understand what's going on.  In this case, setting a breakpoint just before the `while loop` that you're asking about would let you check it.

Comment: I like how the comment says "// While i is <= sqrt(n)" because it's so difficult to figure out what "while (i <= sqrt(n))" does.

Comment: the program runs, but im having trouble understanding why is it running if 2 is less than sqrt(2).

Comment: sorry, im new to programming

Comment: @nhgrif -- your comment is the most appropriate answer to OP's "how does this program run?" question.  In fact, it is better than your answer below.  OP -- run your program through a debugger and step through line by line.

Comment: this is taking out of 'c++ without fear'

Comment: @Juan do the provided comments and answer help you understand what is going on?  If not, what is it that you're still struggling to understand?

Comment: im having trouble understanding how the while loop is running if the user inputs 2 because since i = 2, and 2 is less than the sqrt(2) wouldnt be true.

Comment: @Juan: What makes you think that the loop is running if the user inputs `2`? Where did you get that idea? You have been told already that for `n == 2` the loop simply never runs. Yet you keep repeating that "the loop is running". Why? How? Did you run this program under debugger and saw the the loop body is actually entered?

Comment: The program never enters the body of the `while` loop if the user enters `2`, because, as you've stated, `2 < sqrt(2)`.  `while` and `for` are both pre-check loops.  This means before the body of the loop is entered, the condition statement is checked, and the body of the loop is only entered if the check returns true.

Comment: @Oiclid Asking a good SO question is simple as this: Your implementation  takes some _input_, you're expecting it to return some _output_, it doesn't do as expected when you test it, tell us, what's the difference of your expected _output_ compared to your actual _output_. Is this so hard to get, really? (I've downvoted all the other questions you've asked, without following this simple principle!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `while loop` never enters. `is_prime` is initialized to `true` (not sure why it's an `int` and not a `bool`), so `if(is_prime)` is entered, and `Number is prime.` should print.

Answer (score 0):

If you input `2,2<=sqrt(2)` is `false`. So the while loop never tnters. But you initialized `is_primer` `true`, the `if(is_prime)` will do and output `"Number is primer"`. `2` is a primer. You are right to do like this